# Techniques for Playing Wrench Tennis Effectively?

Tags: bioshock

So, I noticed that in the *Medical Pavilion* stage of Bioshock, there is one hallway you can enter that has a quaint little machine in it.   If you hit a button at the other end of the hallway, this machine starts shooting out tennis balls.  There are various trophies lined up along the wall, and various Tennis racquetes littering the floor in this hallway.

Now, I **did** find what seems to be a fake torso hanging from a pole (apparently to study anatomy, as the front gives access to various organs) in another room on the opposite side of the area, which gave me a cool idea.  After some work, I managed to carry him across the entire area and stand him in front of the machine so that the fired balls were then wildly deflected every which way, which was great at first: but now I want something **more**.

I've tried using the tennis racquets combined with the Telekinesis plasmid, but have been unable to do much more than launch it at the ball in mid-flight, sending both objects off into the far reaches of the next room.

---

So, I was wondering if anyone had any kind of technique for doing a proper forehand or backhand?  I've had some success with the *wrench*, but that's more of an overhand motion, and is **quite** inaccurate.  While extremely entertaining, this isn't exactly what I'm looking for.  I'm basically looking to be able to play a form of *Squash* with myself against the far wall, which requires being able to keep a fair degree of control over one single tennis ball, for an extended period of time.

Comment: I appreciate your sheer single-minded determination to make your own mini-game. Might I suggest that if you succeed, you award yourself one of the trophies as an "achievement"?

Comment: I think I even still have one trophy left in that room! (The rest have all been dumped in toilets somewhere, I fear.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty sure the 'intended way' to play quasi-squash in that room is to just TK the balls back at the wall.

Far less fun than trying to hit them though.

Comment: Indeed it is.  Using the *Sonic Boom* plasmid gives a neat element of unpredictability to the game, but I find I have to use an EVE hypo every 2 or 3 uses, which means I miss the ball on its return...